# How to create a number sequence multicompany?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, sequences, number-sequence

I need to create a custom number sequence, but another request It is to have a *multicompany* Number sequence.

I know how to create a simple sequence, I used this [NumberSeq_Tutorial](https://www.dynamics101.com/creating-custom-number-sequences-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012//).
It's possible to create a Number sequence in a company, launch the

**JOB**

```
static void loadNumSeqCustDemo(Args _args)
{
    //define the class variable
    NumberSeqModuleCustomer seqMod = new NumberSeqModuleCustomer();

    //load the number sequences that were not generated
    seqMod.load();
}
```

and after can use in all anorher company the same Number Sequence. It's possible ?
I need to get a new Number sequence element whe I create e new record in by *form*.

Thanks in advice,

enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See how to [Set up number sequences](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242127.aspx).

On the Scope parameters FastTab, select the Shared scope for the number sequence.

When initializing the number sequence *do not* call the `addParameterType`.
Usually:

```
datatype.addParameterType(NumberSeqParameterType::DataArea, true, false);
this.create(datatype);
```

Instead just:

```
this.create(datatype);
```

I found this [Making a Number Sequence Shared in AX 2012 - Tutorial](http://dynamicserppros.com/making-a-number-sequence-shared-in-ax-2012/) on web.

Comment: Thanks work well.
I hope that you appreciate, I have inserted an another reference for umber Sequence Shared in AX 2012.